# Elastic search suggester and search autocompleter mechanism

Tags: autocomplete, elasticsearch, search-suggestion

I'm researching search engine mechanism and want to implement basic search engine using elastic search. I have 80.000 index document in test elasticsearch cluster. I read elasticsearch tutorial of suggesters and [this article](http://blog.qbox.io/multi-field-partial-word-autocomplete-in-elasticsearch-using-ngrams) . In this article says "This method is not useful for big amount of data". I'm not sure what the method should be. I'm thinking about two ways. I told the first. Second way is using user statistics. Is there any method to accomplish this? What is your suggestion?

Thanks in advance.